# LuaTeX and graphics [TikZ/pstricks]

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, luatex

I'd like to know what LuaTeX offers in terms of graphics: I'm mostly interested in pstricks and TikZ/pgfplots. Could it help TikZ run faster? Would it help TikZ handle 3D non-orthotropic figures (which is not available yet and is CPU consuming)? What could it bring to the pstricks package users?

Comment: Are you offering to write the necessary code :-)

Comment: not really :) I'm super bad at coding anything. I'm just foreseeing interesting coming possibilities. If I can be of any help, I'll be happy though.

Comment: Apart from PSTricks and TikZ, there are other solutions for graphics: metapost, which is in active development and part of LuaTeX/ConTeXt, and Asymptote, which is very good at 3D graphics.

Comment: yes about metapost. I'm not a big fan of asymptote. A luametapost could be nice as well :)

Comment: @Philipp: Metapost is in active development? Who does it?

Comment: @Herbert: Taco and Hans, who else?

Comment: @Philipp: in developing the library for using metapost, but not metapost itself ...

Comment: @Herbert: AFAIK the library *is* the program, and also the executable is in active development.

Comment: @Philipp: the library allows the use of MetaPost inside ConTeXt without running the external program mpost to create a PS compatible output. If you say that MP itself is in development, then show me some new features, which were not present in the past? Maybe that I am missing something ...

Comment: @Herbert: See e.g. the [announcement of MetaPost 1.200](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/metapost/2009-May/001647.html) for tons of new features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle, LuaTeX offers more flexibility, and in particular more speed, for Tikz, `pgfplots`, *etc*. This is because the work (especially floating-point maths) is going to be much easier to do in Lua than in TeX. On the other hand, PStricks uses the PostScript language for the hard work, and it already offers native support for a lot of this work. So there is much less scope for assisting there. (Herbert may have more to say on PStricks, I suspect.)

Comment: A Lua backend for pgf-math would be really useful!

Comment: @Caramdir. Probably not so hard, as you need to do very little for most of the maths, and it becomes a 'glue job'. I guess it is a question of time. (At some stage, we'll need to think about this for LaTeX3, but at the moment I'd prefer to focus on other issues.)

Comment: @Joseph: can you elaborate on "we'll need to think about this for LaTeX3". Thanks. And yes, that'd be great if Herbert could comment on pstricks and LuaTeX.

Comment: @pluton. There are places (for example floating-point work) were it's possible to do stuff with TeX but would be much faster in Lua. So there will be areas where we'll want to have TeX code for pdfTeX and XeTeX, with a Lua alternative 'hidden' within the same LaTeX3 interface. See the `l3fp` module, where I'd like to implement `\fp_div:Nn`, _etc._ in Lua. The idea would be that for packages that do not _require_ LuaTeX there is still a performance benefit without needing to worry about the detail (of course, I have to do that).

Comment: I've done some testing, and it turns out that pgf's non-floating point math functions are faster than Lua's. Of course the Lua functions offer higher precision and a bigger range than any calculations with TeX's dimensions can achieve.

Comment: @Caramdir. That is certainly interesting. I guess you'd need to test some real-world cases, as the balance between real and integer functions will be important.

Comment: @Joseph: So the LaTeX3 team is convinced by Lua as language (hiddenly) extending LaTeX possibilities? Any other language for the same purposes is not recommended?

Comment: @pluton err, what other language is available? If you mean something like PerlTeX, then no, as a longterm solution another language is not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

Recently the developer of tkz-euclide, tkz-graphe and [some other graphics package](http://altermundus.fr/pages/tkz.html) has announced on [fr.comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/fr.comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/1b3d201886e79b67#) that he will adapts his code to Lua (now it's gnuplot who does the job to calculate coordinate).

P.S. I would like to do a comment of these «answer», but i haven't enough reputation yet to comment